# Unable to read a file in FutureAccessList

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to read a CSV file chosen with a `OpenFilePicker` and put into the `FutureAccessList`. But whenever I try to read it I get an `DeniedAccessException`.

That function is a test :

```cs
private async Task readCSVCustomAsync()
{
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    StorageFile file;
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    //picking a file with FilePicker
    file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    //Storing file in futureaccesslist
    string faToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);

    //getting the file from FA list
    var fileOpenTest = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(faToken);

    //trying to read it
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileOpenTest.Path)) //Exception here
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        //elimination des premieres lignes avant le header
        bool headerOK = false;
        while (csv.Read() && !headerOK)
        {
            string rec = csv.GetField(0) + csv.GetField(1);
            if (!rec.Equals(""))
            {
                csv.ReadHeader();
                headerOK = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here I'm trying to put the file in the FA List and retrieve it later to read the content (it's a csv file that I picked).

But even if I put it in the `FutureAccessList` I get an `AccessDeniedException` when I'm trying to read it, why I am getting that exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to read a file in FutureAccessList

The problem is you could not use  `System.IO.StreamReader` to access file where in the `FutureAccessList` with path, and the path property only available in the Windows Storage API. So you need  to open the file as steam, then invoke this  `var reader = new StreamReader(stream)`.

```
private async Task readCSVCustomAsync()
{
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    StorageFile file;
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    //picking a file with FilePicker
    file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    //Storing file in futureaccesslist
    string faToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);

    //getting the file from FA list
    var fileOpenTest = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(faToken);
     // open file as stream, to avoid using path property
    var stream = await fileOpenTest.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    //trying to read it
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) 
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        //elimination des premieres lignes avant le header
        bool headerOK = false;
        while (csv.Read() && !headerOK)
        {
            string rec = csv.GetField(0) + csv.GetField(1);
            if (!rec.Equals(""))
            {
                csv.ReadHeader();
                headerOK = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was wondering if the error could come from the `Path` property and yes it was.